# How to indent this CSS code? It's produces a gallery output

Tags: html, css, gallery

I want to indent my gallery of images to the right because i have a side subtoolbar on my left side. I tried the `left: 200;` code but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

```
<style>
div.images {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

div.images:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.images images {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
```

...

```
<a target="_blank" href="PICS/My Drawings/1.jpg">
    <img src="PICS/My Drawings/1.jpg" alt="Forest" width="200" height="300">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="images">
  <a target="_blank" href="PICS/My Drawings/2.jpg">
    <img src="PICS/My Drawings/2.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="200" height="300">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="images">
  <a target="_blank" href="PICS/My Drawings/3.jpg">
    <img src="PICS/My Drawings/3.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="200" height="300">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: float right instead of left?

Comment: tried but i wanted it to indent in a specific place like when you call left:200

Comment: you can float right and use right or negative left https://jsfiddle.net/0aw5pu5z/ ....some screenshots and live demo will help to understand all your code

Comment: I did that but it seems it won't work in this code.

Comment: @DaniP i did it! I just need to add position: relative in my code lol